# Javascript Reg Exp match a sentence with the words "phone number" but without the word "my" somewhere before

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match a sentences that include the words "phone number" but without sentences that have the word "my" anywhere before the "phone number".

I have tried: `(?<!\bmy\s)(p[^\s]*h[^\s]*n[^\s]*e|t[^\s]*l[^\s]*p[^\s]*n)\s+number`

Which (as expected) doesn't match:
`where do i enter my phone number in your form?`

But does match (Not as expected)
`this is my awesome phone number`

Basically if the word `my` is somewhere in the sentence before `phone number` then i want it to fail.

- Look behinds are supported.

Comment: A negative lookahead might be quite nice here: `^(?!.*\bmy\b.*\bphone number\b).*\bphone number\b.*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead to check if the word my comes before phone number and then match the string including phone number:

```
^(?!.*?\bmy\b.*\bphone number\b).*\bphone number\b.*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hCmn2J/1)

That will match:

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?!.*?\bmy\b.*\bphone number\b)` Assert that the string does not contain my before phone number
- `.*` Match any char 0+ times
- `\bphone number\b` Math phone number between word boundaries to prevent a larger match of the words
- `.*` Math any char  0+ times
- `$` End of the string

Comment: Can you please explain what is the meaning of `\bphone number\b` being used twice?

Comment: First you want to make sure that `my` is not before  phone number. That assertion will also succeed when there is no `phone number` at all. So when matching, you want to make sure that  phone number is actually there. An example of the match when only used in the lookahead: https://regex101.com/r/KpKmnH/1

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general regex which should work:

```
^(?!.*\bmy\b.*\bphone number\b).*\bphone number\b.*$
```

### Demo

This uses a negative lookahead to ensure that `my` does not come before `phone number.  Then, it matched`phone number` anywhere in the sentence.

Here is some JavaScript code:

```
var sentence = 'This is my phone number';
/^(?!.*\bmy\b.*\bphone number\b).*\bphone number\b.*$/.test(sentence); // false
sentence = 'I have a phone number.';
/^(?!.*\bmy\b.*\bphone number\b).*\bphone number\b.*$/.test(sentence); // true
```